# Print blanks instead of error/undefined in winston log

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

Is it possible to configure winston logging so when a variable is not defined , it is printed as `key:""` instead of an error message being displayed.

Basically, I am trying to log some metadata that I get from users, and it is not available everywhere, and I want it to print the empty value with the key everywhere if its not there.